# Is this a synchronization issue? Using Google translate to chain-translate words.

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, concurrency, google-translate

I'm trying to write a script that will allow me to quickly examine how a word changes when translated multiple times by Google translate. Unfortunately, I'm not very experienced with Javascript and I can't pin down the source of the problem I'm having:

```
function initialize() {
    var word = "Hello";
    var english = [word];
    var german = [];
    document.write("1");

    var i = 0;
    for  (i=0; i<10; i++) {

        google.language.translate(english[i], 'en', 'de', function(result) {
            if (!result.error) {
                german.push(result.translation);
                document.write(result.translation); 
            }
            else {
                document.write(result.error.message);
            }
            document.write("2");
        });

        document.write("3");

        google.language.translate(german[i], 'de', 'en', function(result) {
            if (!result.error) {
                english.push( result.translation );
                document.write ( result.translation );
            }
            else {
                document.write(result.error.message);
            }
            document.write("4");
        });

        document.write("5");

    }
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

As you can see, the second call to google.language.translate takes as an argument the result of the first call. I expect to see something like this in the document when this is run:

1Hallo23Hello45Hallo23Hello45Hallo23Hello45 ...

Instead I get 13Hallo2 and a crash. Because it prints 1and 3 (ie it executes the doc.write("3") before it executes all of the first call to translate) I suspect some sort of asynchronous behavior is going on. I'm used code that executes in the order I wrote it! Help! Ideally I'd like to know how I can get the rest of the loop to only execute after the first call to google translate has returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's indeed a synchronization issue. When you call the first `google.language.translate`, you pass in a callback, but that callback isn't executed immediately - only after `translate` gets a translation from the server. In the mean time, the code continues to run, and executes the second `google.language.translate`, passing in `german[i]`, which is probably undefined at that point.

To serialize the execution of those a-sync calls, you can place the second call to `google.language.translate` inside the callback of the first one, after the `document.write("2")`. This will ensure `german[i]` is set before used.

Comment: I made this modification and after a bit of fiddling with push, it fixed the problem. Thanks!